# Sorting using the sort object in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Trying to sort and remove duplicates from a CSV file (separated by commas) containing some data into a new CSV file.  I get it to work perfectly if I hard code the columns for the -Property parameter. If I try to add the columns dynamically so I can use it for different projects. It does not work.

Below is the code that works and after is the code that does not:

Works

```
$Source = 'e:\Temp\DataFromSkywardEdited.csv';
$Destination = 'e:\Temp\DataFromSkywardRD.csv';
$SortByColNames = 'LastName,FirstName';

Get-Content $Source |
      ConvertFrom-Csv | 
    Sort -Property LastName,FirstName -Unique |
    ForEach {"{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8}" -f $_.EmployeeID.Trim(), $_.FirstName.Trim(), $_.LastName.Trim(), $_.Location.Trim(), $_.Department.Trim(), $_.TelephoneNo.Trim(), $_.Email.Trim(), $_.EmpTypeCode.Trim(), $_.EmployeeTypeDescription.Trim()} | 
        Add-Content $Destination
```

Does not work

```
$Source = 'e:\Temp\DataFromSkywardEdited.csv';
$Destination = 'e:\Temp\DataFromSkywardRD.csv';
$SortByColNames = 'LastName,FirstName';

Get-Content $Source |
      ConvertFrom-Csv | 
    Sort -Property $SortByColNames -Unique |
    ForEach {"{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8}" -f $_.EmployeeID.Trim(), $_.FirstName.Trim(), $_.LastName.Trim(), $_.Location.Trim(), $_.Department.Trim(), $_.TelephoneNo.Trim(), $_.Email.Trim(), $_.EmpTypeCode.Trim(), $_.EmployeeTypeDescription.Trim()} | 
        Add-Content $Destination
```

Comment: `'LastName,FirstName'` -> `'LastName','FirstName'`

Comment: Hi Mathias.

Thank you for getting back so fast. Trying to add it into a variable eg, $x = 'LastName, FirstName' and then adding the $x instead of the hard coding it as $x will be from a function parameter.

Comment: The `$SortByColNames` variable in your example is defined as a single string - it's needs to be multiple strings. `$SortByColNames = 'LastName','FirstName'` should work

Comment: Ok let me try. I will let you know. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Mathia. It worked. Had to change generaric variable to an object and separate out the strings as you said. Just having difficulty running it from function parameters. I am good for now will play around more. :-)